# Layering graphical interfaces on top of each other

Tags: python, tkinter, graphics

I have a main program window with a [frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQPfo.png) and a [menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCYEU.png) for invoking calculation modules.

```
from tkinter import Menu, Label, Tk, Frame, Scrollbar, Canvas, N, E, S
import runpy
import Bolt_connection
from importlib import reload

# Program window dimensions
root = Tk()
root.title("Name")
root.geometry("1260x700")
root.update()
MaxX = root.winfo_width()
MaxY = root.winfo_height()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=MaxX, height=MaxY, bg="white")
scroll_y = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)

frame = Frame(canvas)
for i in range(50):
    Label(frame).grid()
    i += 1
canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='nw', window=frame)
canvas.update_idletasks()

canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'),
                 yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)

canvas.grid()
scroll_y.grid(row=0, sticky=E + N + S)
main_menu = Menu()

# Submenu for Export to...
file_menu = Menu(tearoff=0)
help_menu = Menu(file_menu, tearoff=0)
help_menu_export_to = Menu(help_menu, tearoff=0)
help_menu_export_to.add_command(label="Excel")
help_menu_export_to.add_command(label="Word")


def start_bolt_connection():
    import Bolt_connection


def start_key_connection():
    import Key_connection


# Submenu for Part calculation selection
calculation_selection_menu = Menu(tearoff=0)
help_menu2 = Menu(calculation_selection_menu, tearoff=0)
help_menu2_part_calculation_selection = Menu(help_menu2, tearoff=0)
B2 = help_menu2_part_calculation_selection.add_command(label="Bolted (screw) connection", command=start_bolt_connection)
help_menu2_part_calculation_selection.add_command(label="Key connection", command=start_key_connection)
help_menu2_part_calculation_selection.add_command(label="Pinned connection")

# File menu
file_menu.add_command(label="New")
file_menu.add_command(label="Save")
file_menu.add_cascade(label="Export to...", menu=help_menu_export_to)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open")
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit")

# Main menu
main_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="About")
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Help")
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Part calculation selection", menu=help_menu2_part_calculation_selection)


runpy.run_module('Bolt_connection')
root.config(menu=main_menu)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to see a window that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1tYJ.png) when the program starts. Then, when you click on one of the menu buttons (for example, Key connection), the frame should update and display the graphical interface of the new module. After clicking the window should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgzfH.png).

**The problem is that when the graphic part of the new module is displayed, the graphic part of the old module is not erased and they [overlap each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEwVF.png). How to make the program delete the graphic part of the old module? The `grid_remove()` and `reload()` functions do not help.**

**An additional explanation of what I want to get when I run the program.**

1. Program starts.
2. The main window appears with the calculation module already running, installed by default. In this case, "Bolt connection". The window should now look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1tYJ.png).
3. The user selects one of the calculation modules from the menu. In this case, "Key connection". The graphic part of the previous module is erased, and the new module is displayed. The window should now look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgzfH.png).

**UPD**

For a better understanding of the problem, add a link to google drive where the project files are located.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/110OrRqlfzGmswg8cGHO3-C4VxfRj1sos?usp=sharing

In this folder there are two txt files with the code of the exported modules, so that you do not have to download the project to your computer and run it .

Comment: Part of the Problem could be the use of  the geometry manager. You know about columnspan? Then may it could be the size of the pictures. You may need to implement an element that it makes the size of the pictures equally or you resize them with PIL. Its hard to find out whats wrong if we cant see the full code and makes us guess. Maybe you will update your question.

Comment: within a Frame or your window you can only use pack() or grid(). Do you mix the managers?

Comment: Not.  I use only the `grid`. Submit all code does not allow a limit on the number of characters in the question.  I will try to upload the project to the site.

Comment: I guess I missunderstood what you was trying to do.
I think you will do the Modules the same size and lift them up if you want to display them ? Dont you?

Comment: Right. I want to display these modules in a frame specially designed for them in the main window.

Comment: Let me know if I missunderstood you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import Mod1
import Mod2

root = tk.Tk()
m1 = Mod1.Model(root)
m2 = Mod2.Model(root)
m1.grid(column= 0, row=0)
m2.grid(column = 0 ,row=0)

def callback():
    m1.lift()    
b = tk.Button(text='click me', command=callback)
b.grid(column=0,row=1)
```

**Mod1.py**

```
from __main__ import tk

class Model(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.configure(bg="red", width=300, height=300)
```

**Mod2.py**

```
from __main__ import tk

class Model(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.configure(bg="blue", width=300, height=300)
```

**Explaination**

In your Modules you define your Model's as a subclass of tk.Frame, that gives you the ability to handle your Models as same as a tk.Frame.

Comment: Thank you so much!  A little later I will try to use it in my code.
Just in case, I added a link to the Google drive with the project folder in the description of the question.

Comment: You are welcome. But please upvote and accept my answer as soon as it solves your problem. :)

Comment: Your code doesn’t do exactly what I need. Your code first creates an object m1, then m2. That is, m1 is under m2. When the button is pressed, object m1 rises above the object m2. If there are only two or three objects, then this is not a problem. But if there are 10 of them, then it will get a lot of resources.

I want that when the button is pressed, the old object is removed (erased) from the frame, and the new one is drawn.

Comment: @Nemo now that your Models are like tk.Frames you can use widget.destroy() or what you want. Dont you? This is just a exampel, but I could add it to the answer.

Comment: what is difference between `from tkinter import *` and `from __main__ import tk`?

Comment: @xlmaster it isn't a wildcard import which should be avoided anyway. Despite this, it is a showcase, how you would be able to import from `__main__`. Other than that it would be the same as writing `import tkinter as tk`, cause modules in python will just be loaded once.

Comment: hard to understand `tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)` especially what is `tk` as a class in module tkinter, and strangeness of __init__ beside def

Comment: @xlmaster come into tkinter chat, we can help you there.

Comment: @xlmaster Do you want to [join us](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249491/tkinter)?