# Python Tkinter : Display every window on one window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Is there any way to display all the windows in the main window? Like, the top-level widgets coming in one window after another after pressing a button. Normally, top-level widgets come in separate windows, how can I display it in one. And, if can, please give me a method that isn't object-oriented because I don't know that. But any answer is good for me. Thank you.

Comment: You may want to take a look on this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619867/layering-graphical-interfaces-on-top-of-each-other/62620295#62620295

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want by creating a frame inside your main window. The following example does not use an object-oriented approach, but keep in mind that, the more complex your application gets, the more suitable is to use an object-oriented approach.

```
# Import requrired libraries/packages
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Frame, X, TOP

def second_frame(root):
    frameTop=Frame(root, highlightthickness=0, bg="red", height=100)
    frameTop.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)

# Create intance of tkinter
root = Tk(className = 'Python Examples - Window 0')
root.geometry("600x700")
root.resizable(0,0)

# Button to make other content appear
next_button = Button(root, text= 'Next', height =1 , width=5, command=lambda: second_frame(root))
next_button.place(x=30, y =600)

root.mainloop()
```

## Edit

If you just want another window to appear and make the old one to disappear, you can use the following code:

```
# Import requrired libraries/packages
from tkinter import Tk, Checkbutton, IntVar, Button, Toplevel

def second_window(root):
    root1 = Tk(className = 'Python Examples - Window 1')
    root1.geometry("600x700")
    root1.resizable(0,0)
    root.withdraw()

# Create intance of tkinter
root = Tk(className = 'Python Examples - Window 0')
root.geometry("600x700")
root.resizable(0,0)

next_button = Button(root, text= 'Next', height =1 , width=5, command=lambda: second_window(root))
next_button.place(x=30, y =600)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is good but I don't need this. I need this 'Next' button to go to the next window, not add other widgets.

Comment: So you want another window to appear and the old one to disappear? I have just added an edit for this case.