# Running a program inside a Tkinter canvas of Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, subprocess, tkinter-canvas

I want to run a program window(specifically saying, another python program made with tkinter GUI) inside a tkinter canvas or frame of a program written in python.Can I use subprocess library to do that?

Comment: You dont need subprocess for, if you use a OOP solution.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application

Comment: Also take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619867/layering-graphical-interfaces-on-top-of-each-other/62620295#62620295