# How to put together two windows in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have made two windows containing Database GUI following a tutorial. Every window is in a separate module. But I want to make a bit more complex program. How can I put them together into one window, so I can switch between them using something like a menu.
First window (Customers.py):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import mysql.connector as mysql




class CustomerDB:

def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root
    titlespace = " "
    self.root.title(102 * titlespace + "Adamant Studio")
    self.root.geometry("900x700+300+0")
    self.root.resizable(width = False, height = False)

    


    MainFrame = Frame(self.root, bd = 10, width = 770, height = 700, relief = RIDGE, bg = 'cadet blue')
    MainFrame.grid()
    mainmenu  = Menu(MainFrame)

    self.root.config(menu = mainmenu)
    mainmenu.add_command(label = "Save")  

    TitleFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd = 7, width = 770, height = 100, relief = RIDGE)
    TitleFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    TopFrame3 = Frame(MainFrame, bd = 5, width = 770, height = 500, relief  = RIDGE)
    TopFrame3.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    LeftFrame = Frame(TopFrame3, bd=5, width = 770, height = 400, padx = 2, bg = "cadet blue", relief = RIDGE)
    LeftFrame.pack(side = LEFT)
    LeftFrame1 = Frame(LeftFrame, bd = 5, width = 600, height = 180, padx = 12, pady = 9, relief = RIDGE)
    LeftFrame1.pack(side = TOP)

    RightFrame1 = Frame(TopFrame3, bd = 5, width = 100, height = 400, padx = 2, bg = "cadet blue", relief = RIDGE)
    RightFrame1.pack(side = RIGHT)
    RightFrame1a = Frame(RightFrame1, bd = 5, width = 90, height = 300, padx = 2, pady = 2, relief = RIDGE)
    RightFrame1a.pack(side = TOP)

    mainmenu  = Menu(MainFrame)

    #====================================================================================================================================================
    CustomerID = StringVar()
    Firstname = StringVar()
    Lastname = StringVar()
    Patronymic = StringVar()
    Order = StringVar()
    Phone = StringVar()
    Email = StringVar()
    #====================================================================================================================================================

    def iExit():
        iExit = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno("Adamant Studio", "Confirm if you want to exit")
        if iExit > 0:
            root.destroy()
            return 


    def Reset():
        self.entcustomersID.delete(0, END)
        self.entFirstname.delete(0, END)
        self.entLastname.delete(0, END)
        self.entPatr.delete(0, END)
        self.entOrdnum.delete(0, END)
        self.entPhone.delete(0, END)
        self.entEmail.delete(0, END)

    def addData():
        if CustomerID.get() == "" or Firstname.get() == "" or Lastname.get() == "":
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Adamant Studio", "Enter Correct Details")
        else:
            con = mysql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "060178Jb!", database = 'adamant')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("insert into Customers values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (CustomerID.get(), 
    Firstname.get(), 
    Lastname.get(),
    Patronymic.get(), 
    Order.get(), 
    Phone.get(),
    Email.get()))
            con.commit()
            con.close()
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Adamant Studio", "Record Entered Successfully")


    def DisplayData():
        con = mysql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "060178Jb!", database = 'adamant')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("select * from Customers")
        result = cur.fetchall()
        if len(result) !=0:
            self.customers_records.delete(*self.customers_records.get_children())
            for row in result:
                self.customers_records.insert('', END, values = row)
        con.commit()
        con.close()

    def CustomerInfo(ev):
        viewInfo = self.customers_records.focus()
        customerData = self.customers_records.item(viewInfo)
        row = customerData['values']
        CustomerID.set(row[0])
        Firstname.set(row[1]), 
        Lastname.set(row[2]),
        Patronymic.set(row[3]), 
        Order.set(row[4]), 
        Phone.set(row[5]),
        Email.set(row[6])


    def update():
        con = mysql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "060178Jb!", database = 'adamant')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("update Customers set Firstname = %s, Lastname = %s, Patronymic = %s, OrderNumber = %s, Phone = %s, email = %s where CustomerID = %s", (
        Firstname.get(), 
        Lastname.get(),
        Patronymic.get(), 
        Order.get(), 
        Phone.get(),
        Email.get(), 
        CustomerID.get() ))
        con.commit()
        DisplayData()
        con.close()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Adamant Studio", "Record Updated Successfully")


    def deleteData():
        con = mysql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "060178Jb!", database = 'adamant')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("delete from Customers where CustomerID = %s",CustomerID.get()) 

        con.commit()
        DisplayData()
        con.close()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Adamant Studio", "Record Successfully Deleted")
        Reset()


    def searchDB():
        try:
            con = mysql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "060178Jb!", database = 'adamant')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("select * from Customers where CustomerID = %s", CustomerID.get()) 

            row = cur.fetchall()

            CustomerID.set(row[0])
            Firstname.set(row[1]), 
            Lastname.set(row[2]),
            Patronymic.set(row[3]), 
            Order.set(row[4]), 
            Phone.set(row[5]),
            Email.set(row[6])

            con.commit()
        except:
            
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Adamant Studio", "No Such Record Found")
            Reset()
        con.close()



    #====================================================================================================================================================
    self.lbltitle = Label(TitleFrame, font = ('arial', 40, 'bold'), text = "ADAMANT STUDIO", bd = 7)
    self.lbltitle.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 132)

    self.lblcustomersID = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "CustomersID", bd = 7)
    self.lblcustomersID.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entcustomersID = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = CustomerID)
    self.entcustomersID.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)

    self.lblFirstname = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "Firstname", bd = 7)
    self.lblFirstname.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entFirstname = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = Firstname)
    self.entFirstname.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)

    self.lblLastname = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "Lastname", bd = 7)
    self.lblLastname.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entLastname = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = Lastname)
    self.entLastname.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)

    self.lblPatr = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "Patronymic", bd = 7)
    self.lblPatr.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entPatr = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = Patronymic)
    self.entPatr.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)

    self.lblOrdnum = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "Order number", bd = 7)
    self.lblOrdnum.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entOrdnum = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = Order)
    self.entOrdnum.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)

    self.lblPhone = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "Phone", bd = 7)
    self.lblPhone.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entPhone = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = Phone)
    self.entPhone.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)

    self.lblEmail = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "Email", bd = 7)
    self.lblEmail.grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entEmail = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = Email)
    self.entEmail.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)



    scroll_y = Scrollbar(LeftFrame, orient = VERTICAL)

    self.customers_records = ttk.Treeview(LeftFrame, height = 14, columns = ("CustomerID", "Firstname", "Lastname", "Patronymic", "Order", "Phone", "Email"), yscrollcommand = scroll_y.set)

    scroll_y.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)

    self.customers_records.heading("CustomerID", text = "CustomerID")
    self.customers_records.heading("Firstname", text = "Firstname")
    self.customers_records.heading("Lastname", text = "Lastname")
    self.customers_records.heading("Patronymic", text = "Patronymic")
    self.customers_records.heading("Order", text = "Order")
    self.customers_records.heading("Phone", text = "Phone")
    self.customers_records.heading("Email", text = "Email")

    self.customers_records['show'] = 'headings'

    self.customers_records.column("CustomerID", width = 90)
    self.customers_records.column("Firstname", width = 100)
    self.customers_records.column("Lastname", width = 100)
    self.customers_records.column("Patronymic", width = 100)
    self.customers_records.column("Order", width = 70)
    self.customers_records.column("Phone", width = 100)
    self.customers_records.column("Email", width = 100)

    self.customers_records.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
    self.customers_records.bind("<ButtonRelease>", CustomerInfo)
    DisplayData()

    




    self.btnAddNew = Button(RightFrame1a, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), text = 'Add New', bd = 4, pady = 1, padx = 24, width = 8, height = 2, command = addData).grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx =1)
    self.btnDisplay = Button(RightFrame1a, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), text = 'Display', bd = 4, pady = 1, padx = 24, width = 8, height = 2, command = DisplayData).grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx =1)
    self.btnUpdate = Button(RightFrame1a, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), text = 'Update', bd = 4, pady = 1, padx = 24, width = 8, height = 2, command = update).grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx =1)
    self.btnDelete = Button(RightFrame1a, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), text = 'Delete', bd = 4, pady = 1, padx = 24, width = 8, height = 2, command = deleteData).grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx =1)
    self.btnSearch = Button(RightFrame1a, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), text = 'Search', bd = 4, pady = 1, padx = 24, width = 8, height = 2, command = searchDB).grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx =1)
    self.btnReset = Button(RightFrame1a, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), text = 'Reset', bd = 4, pady = 1, padx = 24, width = 8, height = 2, command = Reset).grid(row = 5, column = 0, padx =1)
    self.btnExit = Button(RightFrame1a, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), text = 'Exit', bd = 4, pady = 1, padx = 24, width = 8, height = 2, command = iExit).grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx =1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    application = CustomerDB(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[First window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uio4f.png)

Second window (Employees.py)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import mysql.connector as mysql


class EmployeeDB:

def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root
    titlespace = " "
    self.root.title(102 * titlespace + "Adamant Studio")
    self.root.geometry("1000x700+300+0")
    self.root.resizable(width = False, height = False)

    


    MainFrame = Frame(self.root, bd = 10, width = 770, height = 700, relief = RIDGE, bg = 'cadet blue')
    MainFrame.grid()
    mainmenu  = Menu(MainFrame)

    self.root.config(menu = mainmenu)
    mainmenu.add_command(label = "Save")  

    TitleFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd = 7, width = 770, height = 100, relief = RIDGE)
    TitleFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    TopFrame3 = Frame(MainFrame, bd = 5, width = 770, height = 500, relief  = RIDGE)
    TopFrame3.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    LeftFrame = Frame(TopFrame3, bd=5, width = 770, height = 400, padx = 2, bg = "cadet blue", relief = RIDGE)
    LeftFrame.pack(side = LEFT)
    LeftFrame1 = Frame(LeftFrame, bd = 5, width = 600, height = 180, padx = 12, pady = 9, relief = RIDGE)
    LeftFrame1.pack(side = TOP)

    RightFrame1 = Frame(TopFrame3, bd = 5, width = 100, height = 400, padx = 2, bg = "cadet blue", relief = RIDGE)
    RightFrame1.pack(side = RIGHT)
    RightFrame1a = Frame(RightFrame1, bd = 5, width = 90, height = 300, padx = 2, pady = 2, relief = RIDGE)
    RightFrame1a.pack(side = TOP)

    mainmenu  = Menu(MainFrame)

    #====================================================================================================================================================
    EmployeeID = StringVar()
    Firstname = StringVar()
    Lastname = StringVar()
    Patronymic = StringVar()
    Department = StringVar()
    Position = StringVar()
    Phone = StringVar()
    Email = StringVar()
    #====================================================================================================================================================

    def iExit():
        iExit = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno("Adamant Studio", "Confirm if you want to exit")
        if iExit > 0:
            root.destroy()
            return 


    def Reset():
        self.entemployeeID.delete(0, END)
        self.entFirstname.delete(0, END)
        self.entLastname.delete(0, END)
        self.entPatr.delete(0, END)
        self.entDepartment.delete(0, END)
        self.entPosition.delete(0, END)
        self.entPhone.delete(0, END)
        self.entEmail.delete(0, END)

    def addData():
        if EmployeeID.get() == "" or Firstname.get() == "" or Lastname.get() == "":
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Adamant Studio", "Enter Correct Details")
        else:
            con = mysql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "060178Jb!", database = 'adamant')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("insert into Employees values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (EmployeeID.get(), 
    Firstname.get(), 
    Lastname.get(),
    Patronymic.get(), 
    Department.get(),
    Position.get(), 
    Phone.get(),
    Email.get()))
            con.commit()
            con.close()
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Adamant Studio", "Record Entered Successfully")


    def DisplayData():
        con = mysql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "060178Jb!", database = 'adamant')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("select * from Employees")
        result = cur.fetchall()
        if len(result) !=0:
            self.employee_records.delete(*self.employee_records.get_children())
            for row in result:
                self.employee_records.insert('', END, values = row)
        con.commit()
        con.close()

    def CustomerInfo(ev):
        viewInfo = self.employee_records.focus()
        employeeData = self.employee_records.item(viewInfo)
        row = employeeData['values']
        EmployeeID.set(row[0])
        Firstname.set(row[1]), 
        Lastname.set(row[2]),
        Patronymic.set(row[3]), 
        Department.set(row[4]),
        Position.set(row[5]), 
        Phone.set(row[5]),
        Email.set(row[6])


    def update():
        con = mysql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "060178Jb!", database = 'adamant')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("update Employees set Firstname = %s, Lastname = %s, Patronymic = %s, Department = %s, Position = %s, Phone = %s, Email = %s where EmployeeID = %s", (
        Firstname.get(), 
        Lastname.get(),
        Patronymic.get(), 
        Department.get(), 
        Position.get(),
        Phone.get(),
        Email.get(), 
        EmployeeID.get() ))
        con.commit()
        DisplayData()
        con.close()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Adamant Studio", "Record Updated Successfully")


    def deleteData():
        con = mysql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "060178Jb!", database = 'adamant')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("delete from Employees where EmployeeID = %s", EmployeeID.get()) 

        con.commit()
        DisplayData()
        con.close()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Adamant Studio", "Record Successfully Deleted")
        Reset()


    def searchDB():
        try:
            con = mysql.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = "060178Jb!", database = 'adamant')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("select * from Employees where EmployeeID = %s", EmployeeID.get()) 

            row = cur.fetchall()

            EmployeeID.set(row[0])
            Firstname.set(row[1]), 
            Lastname.set(row[2]),
            Patronymic.set(row[3]),
            Department.set(row[4]) 
            Position.set(row[5]), 
            Phone.set(row[6]),
            Email.set(row[7])

            con.commit()
        except:
            
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Adamant Studio", "No Such Record Found")
            Reset()
        con.close()



    #====================================================================================================================================================
    self.lbltitle = Label(TitleFrame, font = ('arial', 40, 'bold'), text = "ADAMANT STUDIO", bd = 7)
    self.lbltitle.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 132)

    self.lblemployeeID = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "EmployeeID", bd = 7)
    self.lblemployeeID.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entemployeeID = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = EmployeeID)
    self.entemployeeID.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)

    self.lblFirstname = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "Firstname", bd = 7)
    self.lblFirstname.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entFirstname = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = Firstname)
    self.entFirstname.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)

    self.lblLastname = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "Lastname", bd = 7)
    self.lblLastname.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entLastname = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = Lastname)
    self.entLastname.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)

    self.lblPatr = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "Patronymic", bd = 7)
    self.lblPatr.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entPatr = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = Patronymic)
    self.entPatr.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)

    self.lblDepartment = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "Department", bd = 7)
    self.lblDepartment.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entDepartment = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = Department)
    self.entDepartment.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)

    self.lblPosition = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "Position", bd = 7)
    self.lblPosition.grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entPosition = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = Position)
    self.entPosition.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)

    self.lblPhone = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "Phone", bd = 7)
    self.lblPhone.grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entPhone = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = Phone)
    self.entPhone.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)

    self.lblEmail = Label(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), text = "Email", bd = 7)
    self.lblEmail.grid(row = 8, column = 0, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)
    self.entEmail = Entry(LeftFrame1, font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), bd = 7, width = 44, justify = 'left', textvariable = Email)
    self.entEmail.grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = 'W', padx = 5)



    scroll_y = Scrollbar(LeftFrame, orient = VERTICAL)

    self.employee_records = ttk.Treeview(LeftFrame, height = 14, columns = ("EmployeeID", "Firstname", "Lastname", "Patronymic", "Department", "Position",  "Phone", "Email"), yscrollcommand = scroll_y.set)

    scroll_y.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)

    self.employee_records.heading("EmployeeID", text = "EmployeeID")
    self.employee_records.heading("Firstname", text = "Firstname")
    self.employee_records.heading("Lastname", text = "Lastname")
    self.employee_records.heading("Patronymic", text = "Patronymic")
    self.employee_records.heading("Department", text = "Department")
    self.employee_records.heading("Position", text = "Position")
    self.employee_records.heading("Phone", text = "Phone")
    self.employee_records.heading("Email", text = "Email")

    self.employee_records['show'] = 'headings'

    self.employee_records.column("EmployeeID", width = 90)
    self.employee_records.column("Firstname", width = 100)
    self.employee_records.column("Lastname", width = 100)
    self.employee_records.column("Patronymic", width = 100)
    self.employee_records.column("Department", width = 70)
    self.employee_records.column("Position", width = 100)
    self.employee_records.column("Phone", width = 100)
    self.employee_records.column("Email", width = 100)

    self.employee_records.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
    self.employee_records.bind("<ButtonRelease>", CustomerInfo)
    DisplayData()

    




    self.btnAddNew = Button(RightFrame1a, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), text = 'Add New', bd = 4, pady = 1, padx = 24, width = 8, height = 2, command = addData).grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx =1)
    self.btnDisplay = Button(RightFrame1a, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), text = 'Display', bd = 4, pady = 1, padx = 24, width = 8, height = 2, command = DisplayData).grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx =1)
    self.btnUpdate = Button(RightFrame1a, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), text = 'Update', bd = 4, pady = 1, padx = 24, width = 8, height = 2, command = update).grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx =1)
    self.btnDelete = Button(RightFrame1a, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), text = 'Delete', bd = 4, pady = 1, padx = 24, width = 8, height = 2, command = deleteData).grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx =1)
    self.btnSearch = Button(RightFrame1a, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), text = 'Search', bd = 4, pady = 1, padx = 24, width = 8, height = 2, command = searchDB).grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx =1)
    self.btnReset = Button(RightFrame1a, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), text = 'Reset', bd = 4, pady = 1, padx = 24, width = 8, height = 2, command = Reset).grid(row = 5, column = 0, padx =1)
    self.btnExit = Button(RightFrame1a, font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), text = 'Exit', bd = 4, pady = 1, padx = 24, width = 8, height = 2, command = iExit).grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx =1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()

    application = EmployeeDB(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[Second window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahmOh.png)

Comment: You have several options and it depends how you want to put them together. Would you like to put them into *frames* and show them by a buttonclick for instance? Or would you like to pop them up in sperated `Toplevel`/*Window*?

Comment: I would like to make something like a menu bar on the top of the main window

Comment: A bar of buttons, some say *NavigationBar*. Is that correct?

Comment: You could be intrested in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62620295/13629335)

Comment: You can also look at this for a menu bar: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_menu.htm scroll down to see the visual example

Comment: Use @username if you are replying to someones comment.

Comment: @Atlas435 Thank you, I have used a Menu widget, but got a problem. When I click on the menu tab to open a window, the previous window doesn't close and the new window appears below the previous one. I will give more details below

Comment: simplest way to go is to destroy the window you dont need anymore.